# System Account not having permission to update external list via BCS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, bcs

My SharePoint administrator granted permissions to services, sp app pool, sp farm adim, and secure store in BCS for me to use but was only able create/delete but not update.
I use SharePoint designer 2013 list workflow to create/delete external list item on SQL DB but not update.  Got permission message on System Account when delete:

> The workflow could not update the item in the external data source. Make sure the user has
>   permissions to access the external data source and update items.

We reviewed the [Posting](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19546/how-to-authenticate-bdc-to-the-external-system) and double checked our steps but still no avail.  Anyone have similar issues or ideas on how to troubleshoot and fix?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand clearly what the problem is. Is the account unable to update items or unable to delete items or both?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please check the account which starts the workflow has enough permission on the external list. (If the workflow starts automatically when new item created, please check the account that created the item. If workflow starts when item is changed, then check the account that modified the item.)

Read more details [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/52b0747c-f0cc-430d-bc3f-c69ccb11f616/sharepoint-designer-workflow-and-external-list?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious). Also check this [blog](http://petersullivan.com.au/2010/12/15/the-workflow-could-not-update-the-item-in-the-external-data-source-make-sure-the-user-has-permissions-to-access-the-external-data-source-and-update-items/) to narrow down it.